# BSD Books - Best books for OpenBSD and FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, bsd

I will begin a thorough study of the OpenBSD and FreeBSD, which are the most complete books?

---

I found these, which are the best?

- [Openbsd books](http://www.openbsd.org/books.html)
- [Freebsd books](http://www.freebsd.org/docs/books.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [The Complete FreeBSD](http://www.lemis.com/grog/Documentation/CFBSD/)
 by Grey Lehey, available for free. Greg is a good guy and used to be part of the FreeBSD core development team. Maybe he still is, I'm not sure. The book is probably a bit out of date, it seems was last updated in 2006, but it would be a start at least.